# Iterate over Consecutive N Columns of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]],columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
print(dff)

A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
10  20  30  40  50  60  70
```

I am Trying to iterate row 1 such that, at a time I could get three Column values at a time
i.e for columns A,B,C then B,C,D, followed by D,E,F and E,F,G

Sample Pseudocode:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    # For 1 row run iteration for consecutive 3 columns and print results.
    Print(#some function output)
    Print("*******")
```

Expected Output:

```
1,2,3
2,3,4
3,4,5
4,5,6
5,6,7
*******
10,20,30
20,30,40
30,40,50
40,50,60
50,60,70
```

I was trying to iterate through columns but couldn't find the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
a = np.concatenate( [np.array([np.array(x[i:i+3]) for i in range(len(x)-2)]) for x in df.values])
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df
Out[226]: 
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
3   4   5   6
4   5   6   7
5  10  20  30
6  20  30  40
7  30  40  50
8  40  50  60
9  50  60  70
```